# Simple bind to a class in a WPF app

Tags: wpf, class, data-binding

How do I take a basic class that I've made and extract it's properties in the list in WPF?  I've already tried playing with the itemssource property but nothing seems to have worked for me.

```
Public Class PageContent
    Public StartDate As DateTime
    Public Header As String
    Public Content As String
End Class

<ListView Name="grid_PageContentList" >
     <ListView.View>
       <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StartDate}" Width="50"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Header}" Width="50"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Content}" Width="50"></GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: you're already looking at it.  There is an object, it's bound to the list and now I need to get the list to spit out the values from the objections in the collection.

Comment: What / where are you binding to the list?

Comment: grid_PageContentList.ItemsSource = PageContents 'This is a list(of PageContent)

Comment: That should work.  What happens? Did you check in the debugger that it has data?

Comment: it binds the items but no values show up in the grid for each row.  so you can select the row but you don't see anything in it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5950/discussion-between-middletone-and-slaks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind directly to fields, you need to use properties instead:

```
Public Class PageContent
    Public Property StartDate As DateTime
    Public Property Header As String
    Public Property Content As String
End Class
```

Also you need to ensure you have set you `DataContext`. If you have just a simple form with a code behind approach then put this in the constructor or `Loaded` handler:

```
Class MainWindow 

    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        MyData = New List(Of PageContent)
        Dim pc As New PageContent
        pc.Header = "AAAAAAAA"
        pc.StartDate = Now
        MyData.Add(pc)

        pc = New PageContent
        pc.Header = "BBBBBB"
        pc.StartDate = Now.AddMinutes(1)
        MyData.Add(pc)


        DataContext = Me
    End Sub


    Public Property MyData() As List(Of PageContent)

End Class
```

And set your `ItemsSource` in your XAML:

```
    <ListView Name="grid_PageContentList" ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StartDate}" Width="50"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Header}" Width="50"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Content}" Width="50"></GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: It turns out that all you need is to have properties in your base class.  No need to specify the itemssource.  I should have thought of that first as it's the same for winforms and asp.net gridviews.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make that an ObservableCollection with INPC or a DependencyProperty. Don't just bind regular properties like that as you might not see the data.