# Bind a class member to a listbox

Tags: wpf, list, xaml, binding, listbox

I am a beginner in wpf. In one of my projects I have a frmField class as bellow:

```
public class frmFields
{
    public bool succelssfulEnd = true;
    public string fileName;
    public List<string> errList = new List<string>();
}
```

and a list

```
<ListBox Name="LSTErrors" Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource ="{Binding}"  SelectionChanged="LSTErrors_SelectionChanged" />
```

I need to bind errList to the above listBox in such a way that any change in the List is reflected on the ListBox.

Is there anyone to guide me?

Comment: If you can read VB.Net then I have a previous [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8549710/109702) that will help. Don't forget to set the DataContext of the Window, your ListBox will then inherit that DataContext automatically (unless you reset it somewhere in the visual tree first). And use properties or dependency properties, not fields.

Answer (score 0):

You need an ObservableCollection to refresh the UI every time it changes.

```
public class frmFields
{
    public bool succelssfulEnd = true;
    public string fileName;

    private ObservableCollection<String> _errList = new ObservableCollection<String>();
    public ObservableCollection<String> ErrList {
        get {return _errList;}
        set {
            _errList = value;
            //your property changed if you need one
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you can only bind to a Property or a DependencyProperty, not a simple public variable like you tried.

In your constructor you'll need to add:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

or in your XAML:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"
```

In your root element. And then bind ItemsSource like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ErrList, Mode=OneWay}">
     ...
</ListBox>
```